# Can you install MIUI themes from different sites?

Tags: miui, themes

I'm installing Miui from Miui.us, and I was wondering if I can install themes from http://miuiandroid.com/, or will those not work?

Comment: Most of those themes are available through the Theme app in MIUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a MIUI theme it will be compatible, but I highly recommend you to use the Themes app that comes built-in your MIUI ROM.